# Apps with same bundleID will have same Sandbox?

Tags: ios, migration, sandbox

We have migrated the app from one account to another. It has the same **bundleID** but definitely different **teamID**. So the **AppID** is different.

My question is

Will my app use the same SandBox or will create another?

Answer (score 1):

If you have transferred the app to another account in AppStore Connect and continue to use the same bundle id then any new versions will be seen as an "update" to users that have already installed the app and the updated version will see the same files/preferences etc that the old version had